# How to access an attribute in the directive validator in AngularJS correctly

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm making a validator which validates valid dates like `MM/YYYY`, but I didn't get how to access an attribute when the model changes:

```
<input id="my-date"
       validate-short-date
       data-max-date="{{thisMonth}}"
       type="text"
       name="myDate"
       data-ng-model="myModelDate">
```

Here is the directive

```
.directive('validateShortDate', ['moment', function(moment) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            var maxDate = false;

            var pattern, regex;
            pattern = '^((0[0-9])|(1[0-2])|[1-9])\/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$';
            regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

            if(!angular.isUndefined(attr.maxDate)) {
                // GOT ONLY ONCE
                maxDate = attr.maxDate;
            }

            ngModel.$validators.maxDate = function(modelValue) {
                // maxDate var is undefined after the first time
                if (maxDate && regex.test(modelValue)) {
                    var modelDate = moment(modelValue, 'MM/YYYY').format('YYYYMM');
                    return modelDate <= maxDate;
                }
                return true;
            };

            ngModel.$validators.valid = function(modelValue) {
                return modelValue === '' || modelValue === null || angular.isUndefined(modelValue) || regex.test(modelValue);
            };
        }
    };
}])
```

The validator `ngModel.$validators.valid` works perfect, but inside `ngModel.$validators.maxDate` i cannot get the `attr.maxDate` but the first time directive fires.

So how can I access to a custom attribute value every time I check the `modelValue`?

I'm not an expert with AngularJS and probably I'm missing something important.

Comment: you can use $watch on model then access attribut with attr.dataMaxDate

Comment: As explained in my answer you can `$observe` attribute changes and then retrigger a validation.

Comment: `// GOT ONLY ONCE`- Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attrs` argument in the link function provides you with a [`$observe`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) method which you can use to attach a listener function for dynamic changes in an attribute value.

It is very simple to use inside of your link function:

```
        attr.$observe('maxDate', function() {
            scope.maxDate = attr.maxDate;
            ngModel.$validate();
        });
```

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/41F7wPIkJNCyzCFoNNN4?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this for track the change in ng-model:-

HTML

```
<input id="my-date"
       validate-short-date
       data-max-date="{{thisMonth}}"
       type="text"
       name="myDate"
       data-ng-model="myModelDate">
```

Angularjs code:-

```
  app.directive('validateShortDate', ['moment', function(moment) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function($scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

                var maxDate = false;

                var pattern, regex;
                pattern = '^((0[0-9])|(1[0-2])|[1-9])\/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$';
                regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

                if(!angular.isUndefined(attr.maxDate)) {
                    // GOT ONLY ONCE
                    maxDate = attr.maxDate;
                }

                ngModel.$validators.maxDate = function(modelValue) {
                    // maxDate var is undefined after the first time
                    if (maxDate && regex.test(modelValue)) {
                        var modelDate = moment(modelValue, 'MM/YYYY').format('YYYYMM');
                        return modelDate <= maxDate;
                    }
                    return true;
                };

                ngModel.$validators.valid = function(modelValue) {
                    return modelValue === '' || modelValue === null || angular.isUndefined(modelValue) || regex.test(modelValue);
                };
            }
       $scope.$watch('ngModel',function(){
          console.log(attr.dataMaxDate);
         });
        };
    }])
```

Comment: It seems to have the same problem, the var `maxDate` is not visible from `ngModel.$validators.maxDate`

Comment: also `scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) { ...` has always `undefined` values and it's fired once

Comment: Are you sure your ng-model doesnot getting undefined in controller